# Square root estimation

Tags: recursion

I happened to read a [something online](http://biesnecker.com/2014/10/12/calculating-the-square-root-of-a-number/) about estimating a square root in a very simple way, known as Heron's method or the [Babylonian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#cite_ref-2) method for square roots. The following (python?) code was included in the post:

```
def heron_sqrt(n, precision=0.000000000001):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    guess = n / 3.0
    while True:
        lastguess = guess
        guess = (guess + (n / guess)) / 2.0
        if abs(lastguess - guess) <= precision:
            break
    return guess
```

What is a good approach to implement this very simple algorithm in a Mathematica function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's fairly simple using `FixedPoint`.

--- edited for safety, per recommendation by @dionys ---

```
heronSqrt[x_/;Element[x,Reals]&&x>=0] := FixedPoint[(# + x/#)/2. &, x/3.]

In[268]:= heronSqrt[2]

(* Out[268]= 1.41421356237 *)
```

Alternatively, seed the initial point with a complex value.

```
heronSqrtForComplexes[x_] := 
 FixedPoint[(# + x/#)/2. &, x/3. + x*I/100.]

heronSqrtForComplexes[-2]

(* Out[201]= 0. - 1.41421356237 I *)
```

Comment: Nice. This still has difficulties with negative numbers though ... and just keeps running, since it doesn't converge.

Comment: @dionys I'm not sure why you would expect it to work with negative numbers though.  There's nothing in the algorithm that will give you a complex number.

Comment: @wxffles It's not a serious question, really. There are better ways to get square roots and no one needs this. It's more like code golf. Negative numbers are just an obvious failing. Maybe there's a better way to do it that can showcase a cool idea that might actually be useful in something else. Anyway, I thought it was fun to puzzle about, which is why I posted it (and my answer below) in the first place.

Comment: Right, I didn't make it bullet proof. Not sure if the original would fare better though.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Wouldn't take much to toss in a PositiveQ condition. Might be a good idea, considering the behavior when it doesn't converge.

Comment: Kinder, gentler version now in place.

Comment: Tougher, meaner version now also in place. Not intended for children or people with heart conditions. Ask your doctor if `heronSqrtForComplexes` is suitable for your healthy usage.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau any particular reason for choosing a different seed value for the imaginary estimate? +1 for mean version.

Comment: I just wanted it to be a smallish offset. Would probably be better to use a random small value, in case there remains a "bad ray" as there was with the negative reals in the earlier version.

Answer (score 2):

Using `NestList` seems like a decent approach:

```
HeronSqrt[x_, n_: 5] := Module[{f},
  f[num_, est_] := N@Mean[{est, num/est}];
  NestList[f[x, #] &, x/3., n]]

HeronSqrt[36]
```

> ```
> {12., 7.5,6.15, 6.00183, 6., 6.}
> ```

But I'm sure there are nicer ways to implement this. For instance, the above doesn't do so well with negative numbers:

```
HeronSqrt[-4, 100] // ListPlot
```

> [image]